# Updating AtomicBoolean from within lambda expression

Tags: java, android, asynchronous, aws-lambda, aws-amplify

I'm passing a lambda expression as an argument to a method, and I want to modify a variable that is defined *outside* of the lambda expression.

I've tried a few things. Currently, I have an `AtomicBoolean` called `success`. Within the lambda expression, I'm calling `success.set(true)`. However, when I log the value of the `success` variable, it's still `false` and doesn't seem to be updating.

Basically, I'm calling a function with a void return type and need to know if the function was successful.

What am I doing wrong?

Here's the code:

```java
public void createUser(String email, String password) {
    AtomicBoolean success = new AtomicBoolean(false);
    Amplify.Auth.signUp(
        email,
        password,
        AuthSignUpOptions.builder()
            .userAttribute(AuthUserAttributeKey.email(), email)
            .build(),
        result -> success.set(true),
        error -> Log.e("AuthQuickStart", "Sign up failed", error)
    );
    Log.d("success", String.valueOf(success.get()));
}
```

Comment: Please show us the code - it's really hard to work out what's wrong in code we can't see. If you can reduce this to a [mcve] that would be even better.

Comment: Yep, your description suggests nothing wrong, a code sample is required.

Comment: Sorry, i've updated with the code now

Comment: @Brian16446 Are you sure that the callback runs before you exit the method?

Comment: I suspect the `signUp` method is asynchronous: it returns immediately and runs on another thread. So your boolean will not be set yet when you check it.

Answer (score 2):

If the `signUp` method is blocking (i.e. it returns once the signup is finished), your code should work as expected. So I suspect it is asynchronous.

In that case, on top of using a boolean, you could also use a `CountDownLatch`  to wait until the async method completes:

```
AtomicBoolean success = new AtomicBoolean(false);
CountDownLatch done = new CountDownLatch(1);
Amplify.Auth.signUp(
        email,
        password,
        AuthSignUpOptions.builder().userAttribute(AuthUserAttributeKey.email(), email).build(),
        result -> { success.set(true); done.countDown(); },
        error -> { Log.e("AuthQuickStart", "Sign up failed", error); done.countDown(); }
);
done.await(); //you may want to add a timeout here
Log.d("success", String.valueOf(success.get()));
```

Comment: I've tried looking for the signup method online but can't find it anywhere and the android amplify documentation isn't great. I'll try this out thanks

Comment: @Brian16446 The `signUp(..)` method is documented in this section on "registering a user": https://docs.amplify.aws/lib/auth/signin/q/platform/android#register-a-user

Comment: @Jameson yeah I saw that, I meant I couldn't find info about the return type, all optional parameters and such

Answer (score 1):

An `AtomicBoolean` variable (`success`) is used correctly. Most probably,

```
Log.d("success", String.valueOf(success.get()));
```

is called before

```
result -> success.set(true)
```

because of asynchronous execution of callback. Alternatively result callback is not called at all.

**You can test it by changing callback body to:**

```
 result -> {
     Log.d("callback test", "callback start");
     result -> success.set(true);
     Log.d("callback test", "callback end");
}
```

If `"callback test"` doesn't appear in the logs then callback is not called.
If `"callback test"` appear after `"success"` then callback body is called after `Log.d("success", String.valueOf(success.get()));` due to asynchronous execution.

Answer (score 1):

@assylias's and @jakub-bialy's answers are totally valid. However, neither considers the `error` callback. Additionally, using a `CountDownLatch` directly is a little low-level.

Amplify provides an [`rxbindings`](https://github.com/aws-amplify/amplify-android/tree/main/rxbindings#amplify-android-rxbindings) module, which can help simplify asynchronous programming.

In your case, you could use [the Rx version of the `signUp(...)` method](https://github.com/aws-amplify/amplify-android/blob/main/rxbindings/src/main/java/com/amplifyframework/rx/RxAuthCategoryBehavior.java#L44-L58), like so:

```java
// Change your initialization to:
RxAmplify.addPlugin(new AWSCognitoAuthPlugin())
RxAmplify.configure(getApplicationContext())

// Sign-up, in a blocking way:
AuthSignUpOptions options = AuthSignUpOptions.builder()
    .userAttribute(AuthUserAttributeKey.email(), email)
    .build();
AuthSignUpResult result =
    RxAmplify.Auth.signUp(email, password, options)
        .timeout(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
        .blockingGet();
```

The `signUp(...)` call in this case will throw the `error` in a blocking way, in the thread that makes the call. In the other answers, this `error` is ignored.

Comment: This is great and those links are very helpful, thank you